# Update Value from 2nd doc based on compared result

Tags: c#, xml

Generally, what I'm wanting to do is:

`If doc1.Element(A).Value = doc2.Element(B).Value
Then doc2.Element(B).Value = doc1.Element(C).Value
save doc2`

Note:  Both documents have different structures.

doc1.xml

```
<Root>
  <Elements Letters = "abc">
    <Sub1 />
    <Sub2 />
    <sub3>def</sub3>
  </Elements>
  <Elements Letters = "ghi">
    <Sub1 />
    <Sub2 />
    <sub3>jkl</sub3>
  </Elements>
</Root>
```

doc2.xml

```
<DiffRoot>
  <DiffElements>
    <DiffSub1 />
    <DiffSub2>ghi</DiffSub2>
    <DiffSub3 />
    <DiffSub4 />
    <DiffSub5 />
  </DiffElements>
  <DiffElements>
    <DiffSub1 />
    <DiffSub2>abc</DiffSub2>
    <DiffSub3 />
    <DiffSub4 />
    <DiffSub5 />
  </DiffElements>
</DiffRoot>
```

Here I'm wanting to compare doc1.Elements(Letters) with doc2.DiffSub2 and if equal, replace doc2.DiffSub2 with doc1.Sub3.

Resulting doc2.xml

```
<DiffRoot>
  <DiffElements>
    <DiffSub1 />
    <DiffSub2>jkl</DiffSub2>
    <DiffSub3 />
    <DiffSub4 />
    <DiffSub5 />
  </DiffElements>
  <DiffElements>
    <DiffSub1 />
    <DiffSub2>def</DiffSub2>
    <DiffSub3 />
    <DiffSub4 />
    <DiffSub5 />
  </DiffElements>
</DiffRoot>
```

From looking around, XDocument (LINQ 2 XML?) appears to be the right way to go (vs. XMLDocument). There seems to be several ways to get the Values I need to use.  The one that's easiest for me to understand and works (though may not be what I need for this situation):

```
XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(@"D:\doc1.xml");
XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load(@"D:\doc2.xml");

var comp1 = from r in doc1.Descendants("Elements")
select new
{
    check1 = r.Attribute("Letters").Value,
    replace1 = r.Element("sub3").Value,
};

var comp2 = from r in doc2.Descendants("DiffElements")
select new
{
    check2 = r.Element("DiffSub2").Value,
};
```

I did see where I could use `.Where` for compare and update.  But can't figure out how to point to the other document. I tried:

```
var comp1 = from r in doc1.Descendants("Elements")
select new
{
    check1 = r.Attribute("Letters").Value,
    replace1 = r.Element("sub3").Value,
};

var comp2 = doc2
  .Element("DiffRoot")
  .Elements("DiffElements")
  .Where(e => e.Element("DiffSub2").Value == comp1.check1)
  .Single();

comp2.Element("DiffSub2").Value = comp1.replace1;
```

No joy. Doesn't like the `.check1`.  Also, I don't know if this will index the search to keep things together. Or if I need to put it in a `for` loop.  After a few weeks of looking, trying different 'possible' ways and trying not to ask here, the closest I got was:

```
foreach(var item1 in comp1)
foreach(var item2 in comp2)
    if (item1.check1 == item2.check2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item1.replace1);
    }
```

Which outputs the correct Values I need, but get an error when adding `item2.check2 = item1.replace1` after `Console.Writeline()`.  I feel that I'm close, 
yet fear that I am way off base.  Any help on how I can get this to work would be SO MUCH Appreciated!

Comment: if it's a frequent 'problem' you have to solve, you might want to look at XSLT for easy xml transformations. The .net framework provides helper classes for this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated my answer based on your changed xml structure. You can read the values from doc1 in a dictionary and use that dictionary to lookup replacements for doc2. Note that I'm using XDocument here. That will work for most scenario's. If the memory overhead is too large, because the xml files are too large, you could consider using an `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter` combination instead. (Microsoft BizTalk has the useful class `XmlTranslatorStream` for example). Because XDocument does keep an in-memory copy of your document.

```
string doc1String = "<Root><Elements Letters=\"abc\"><Sub1/><Sub2/><sub3>def</sub3></Elements><Elements Letters=\"ghi\"><Sub1/><Sub2/><sub3>jkl</sub3></Elements></Root>";
string doc2String = "<DiffRoot><DiffElements><DiffSub1/><DiffSub2>ghi</DiffSub2><DiffSub3/><DiffSub4/><DiffSub5/></DiffElements><DiffElements><DiffSub1/><DiffSub2>abc</DiffSub2><DiffSub3/><DiffSub4/><DiffSub5/></DiffElements></DiffRoot>";
var doc1 = XDocument.Parse(doc1String); 
var doc2 = XDocument.Parse(doc2String); // or XDocument.Load(fileName);

// read doc1 letters and substitutions in a dictionary:
var lettersLookup = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var element in doc1.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Elements"))
{
    string letters = element.Attributes().Single(a => a.Name.LocalName == "Letters").Value;
    string substitute = element.Descendants().Single(e => e.Name.LocalName == "sub3").Value;
    lettersLookup[letters] = substitute;
}

// Walk through the diffelements of doc2
foreach (var diffElement in doc2.Descendants()
    .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DiffElements"))
{
    var diffSub2 = diffElement.Descendants().Where(d => d.Name.LocalName == "DiffSub2").Single();

    // Find a matching element in doc1
    if (lettersLookup.TryGetValue(diffSub2.Value, out string substitute))
    {
        diffSub2.Value = substitute;
    }
}

// Produces the requested output
Console.WriteLine(doc2.ToString());
// or doc2.Save(fileName);
```

Comment: I feel so bad!  Good intentions,bad execution. I fixed the xml formatting in my OP.  The only Ellement.Attribute is in doc1 (Letters) and the other 2 are Elements (sub3 and DiffSub2 respectively). Also, both docs may have up to several hundred sets(?) records(?).  However each 'set' will always be compared between "Letters" and "DiffSub2" and if (actually when) equal, replace "DiffSub2" with "sub3".  I hope that makes sense. I will digest your reply and see If I can adjust accordingly. Also Console.WriteLine was for testing. I need to save doc2 with the new Values. TY So Much Jesse!

Comment: @JoeViking I updated my answer to reflect the changes in your question.